# Issues installing Tweepy on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, twitter, pip, tweepy

I'm trying to install Tweepy on an Ubuntu VM and I'm running into way more issues than I should be. My first step was to successfully get pip installed. After that I tried:

```
pip install tweepy
```

which returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line  3020, in <module>
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 616, in _build_master
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 629, in _build_from_requirements
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 807, in resolve
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==1.5.4
```

The most that I can gather from that error message is that it can't find pip version 1.5.4. However, if I ask it whereis pip it returns:

```
pip: /usr/local/bin/pip2.7 /usr/local/bin/pip /usr/share/man/man1/pip.1.gz
```

So I know pip is installed. I decided to try the other method listed and do

```
git clone https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy.git
cd tweepy
python setup.py install
```

But that only seems to partially install with error messages returning. Trying whereis tweepy after that method returns nothing.

Can anyone make sense of why this simple install isn't working for me?

Comment: Does your VM have permission to install software? Can you run the commands as `sudo`?

Comment: Running the commands as sudo was my immediate reaction as well. The error message comes out the same.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved by using another fresh Ubuntu VM install and once again trying the manual installation by using

```
git clone https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy.git
cd tweepy
python setup.py install
```

For whatever reason, it now works. The answer is officially voodoo.